# Поиск названия элемента по его максимальному количеству в бинарном дереве

Tags: бинарное-дерево, c++

По заданию требуется реализовать бинарное дерево для хранения и операций с данными вида: Деталь, Количество, Поставщик(С++). Я составила фрагмент программы нахождения имени поставщика , который поставляет наибольшее количество деталей

```
    struct Ttree *Ttree_max (struct Ttree *temp)
    {
        if (temp==NULL)
        return NULL;
        while (temp->right!= NULL) 
        temp= temp-> right;
        return temp;
    }
```

Однако такой вариант не подходит, необходимо это сделать методом рекурсии, составить функцию, проверяющую всех поставщиков (Name) методом обхода всего дерева с вызовом функции подсчета количества деталей (Const) по каждому поставщику(Name). В процессе подсчета запомнить элемент с наибольшим количеством, а в конце вывести его на экран(Name). Помогите разобраться.
Вот часть кода программы:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

    struct Ttree 
{   int Const;      
    char Name[30];      
    char Detal[30];      
    struct Ttree *left;   
    struct Ttree *right;

};
    struct Ttree* add
    (
     Ttree *beg, int Const, char Name[30], char Detal[30]
    )

   {
      if (!beg) 
        {               
           struct Ttree *temp = new Ttree;
          temp->Const = Const;
          strcpy_s(temp->Name, 30, Name);
          strcpy_s(temp->Detal, 30, Detal);

          temp->left = 0;
          temp->right = 0;
          return temp;
        }
     else if ((Const)>(beg->Const)) 
        {                 
          beg->right = add(beg->right, Const, Name, Detal);
          return beg;
        }
     else 
        {        
          beg->left = add(beg->left, Const, Name, Detal);
          return beg;
        }
    }
```

***_******_***_....***_***___

```
    struct Ttree *Ttree_max (struct Ttree *temp)
    {
        if (temp==NULL)
        return NULL;
        while (temp->right!= NULL) 
        temp= temp-> right;
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: @LHh, а что, собственнно, делает у Вас функция Ttree_max()? Она всегда вернет NULL.

В принципе, идея идти по правым веткам дерева (и обнаружить максимум в конце) -- совершенно правильная, на Вам же нужно *имя поставщика*.

Наверное подойдет что-то вроде:

     char * 
     get_maxConst_name (struct Tree *t, int *maxConst) {
       if (t->right)
          return get_maxConst_name(t->right, maxConst);
       *maxConts = t->Const;
       return t->Name; // или как вариант strdup(t->Name)
     }

Извините, как часто и  бывает, проще написать, чем объяснить -- как и почему надо это делать.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы найти Name поставщика с максимальным количеством деталей, необходимо запомнить текущий максимум и пройтись по всему дереву, заменяя максимум при нахождении большего количества. Это делается примерно так:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void find_max(struct TTree *tree, map<string, int> &strmap, struct Ttree *max)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    string str(tree->Name);
    if (strmap.count(str) == 0)
        strmap[str] = tree->Const;
    else
        strmap[str] += tree->Const;
    if (max == NULL)
        max = tree;
    else
    {
        string maxstr(max->Name);
        if (strmap[str] > strmap[maxstr])
            max = tree;
    }
    find_max(tree->right, strmap, max);
    find_max(tree->left, strmap, max);
}

int main(int argc; char **argv)
{
    map<string, int> names_map;
    struct Ttree *tree;
    fill_tree_initial(tree); // это, я надеюсь, вы реализуете сами
    struct Ttree *max = tree;
    find_max(tree);
    puts(max->Name);
    return 0;
}
```

Ключевым элементом здесь является `map<string, int> &strmap`, которая содержит агрегируемые значения целочисленного типа по каждому поставщику. Заполнение, конечно, получилось слегка сумбурным, но хороший стиль программирования требует поступать именно так (мы не можем гарантировать, что в `max` не будет нуля).

Comment: Спасибо, я уточнила

Comment: @Danatela, Вы **уверены**, что функция `add()` у ТС стороит не дерево, а двусвязный список?

IMHO все-таки дерево бинарное (естественно, балансированное только порядком поступления ключей (в данном случае поля `Const` из `struct Ttree`)).

Посмотрите еще раз внимательней на *отвратительно НЕотформатированную* рекурсивную функцию 

    struct Ttree* add (Ttree *beg, int Const, char Name[30], char Detal[30]) 
    {
       ...
    }

Язык же, судя по возможности смешивать `struct Ttree` с `Ttree` -- кресты.

Comment: @avp вы правы. Я немного не понял вопрос. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Да, возможно повторение. Но может устроить и попроще вариант, когда Name не повторяется, корнем служит количество деталей int Const

Comment: @LHh всё, сделал для повторяющихся значений.

Comment: Я очень благодарна за помощь!!! :))))
Надеюсь, теперь справлюсь

Comment: @Danatela, а зачем так сложно-то?

У автора ведь уже есть бинарное дерево, построенное именно по количеству деталей. 

Поэтому (ключ -- *количество деталей*) такое дерево не надо обходить. Достаточно пройти до конца правую ветвь. Последним листом будет как раз элемент с максимальным количеством деталей.

--

Кстати, даже в дереве, упорядоченном по другому, которое придется обойти полностью, никакой `map` абсолютно не нужен. Достаточно протащить по всем узлам адрес структуры 

     struct result {
        char *name;
        int  max;
     };

в которую в самом начале положить данные корня.

Comment: @avp насколько я понял, необходимо подсчитать количество деталей по каждому поставщику, без учёта имён деталей. А поскольку дерево отсортировано только по количеству деталей (да и сложно его по-другому организовать) а поставщики могут повторяться, лучшего решения, чем `map`, я придумать не могу. Нам ведь где-то нужно хранить значения по каждому поставщику. Если у вас есть решение получше, прошу вас его опубликовать.

Comment: @LHh если вас устраивает моё решение, подумайте над тем, чтобы отметить его как принятое. Это позволит проще его находить в будущем. Кроме того, это стандартный для данного форума способ отблагодарить человека, оказавшего вам помощь.

Comment: @Danatela, возможно я неверно уловил суть вопроса.

Если нужна не максимальная поставка, а максимальная сумма поставок, то да, надо суммировать по каждому поставщику.

--

тогда -- map -- это хорошее решение. 

--

Если же автор еще не проходил STL и от него ждут решения в виде деревьев (скажем, тема такая), то ему надо просто самому как-то реализовать `map`.

Здесь вполне логичным будет выглядеть частное (не обобщенное) решение в виде дерева с ключем -- имя поставщика и с суммой поставок в качестве данных (можно накапливать прямо в функции `add()`) .

Одновременно можно искать максимум.

Answer (score 3):

[[@Danatela](/users/19473/danatela)](/users/19473/danatela), набросал на скорую руку.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct tnode {
  struct tnode *left, *right;
  void *data;
};

struct tdata {
  char sup_name[20], det_name[30];
  unsigned int amount;
};

typedef int (*bt_cmp)(void *data, void *tree_data);

static void
bt_add (struct tnode *root, struct tnode *t, bt_cmp cmp)
{
  if (cmp(t->data, root->data) > 0) {
    if (root->right)
      bt_add(root->right, t, cmp);
    else
      root->right = t;
  } else {
    if (root->left)
      bt_add(root->left, t, cmp);
    else
      root->left = t;
  }
}

static int cmp_amount (void *data, void *tree_data) {
  struct tdata *p = (struct tdata *)data, 
    *q = (struct tdata *)tree_data;

  return p->amount - q->amount;
}

static int cmp_sup (void *data, void *tree_data) {
  struct tdata *p = (struct tdata *)data, 
    *q = (struct tdata *)tree_data;

  return strcmp(p->sup_name, q->sup_name);
}

static int cmp_detail (void *data, void *tree_data) {
  struct tdata *p = (struct tdata *)data, 
    *q = (struct tdata *)tree_data;

  return strcmp(p->det_name, q->det_name);
}

struct tdata *
get_record ()
{
  struct tdata s, *r;
  char str[LINE_MAX];

  fputs("Enter supplier, detail, amount : ", stdout);
  while (fgets(str, LINE_MAX, stdin)) {
    if (sscanf(str, "%s %s %u", s.sup_name, s.det_name, &s.amount) == 3) {
      r = (struct tdata *)malloc(sizeof(*r));
      memcpy(r, &s, sizeof(*r));
      return r;
    }
    puts("Invalid input, try again");
  }

  return 0;
}

static void
add_tree (struct tnode **root, struct tdata *sup, bt_cmp cmp)
{
  struct tnode *p = (struct tnode *)calloc(1, sizeof(*p));
  p->data = (void *)sup;
  if (*root)
    bt_add(*root, p, cmp);
  else
    *root = p;
}

static void 
pri_tree (struct tnode *t, int level)
{
  if (t) {
    pri_tree(t->left, level + 1);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < level; i++)
      fputs("  ", stdout);
    struct tdata *d = (struct tdata *)t->data;
    printf ("%s %s %u\n", d->sup_name, d->det_name, d->amount);
    pri_tree(t->right, level + 1);
  }
}

static void 
find_max (struct tnode *t, struct tdata **dmax)
{
  if (t) {
    find_max(t->left, dmax);
    find_max(t->right, dmax);
    struct tdata *d = (struct tdata *)t->data;
    if (d->amount > (*dmax)->amount)
      *dmax = d;
  }
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct tdata *sup;
  struct tnode *atree = 0, *dtree = 0;

  while(sup = get_record()) {
    add_tree(&atree, sup, cmp_amount);
    add_tree(&dtree, sup, cmp_detail);
  }
  puts("");
  if (!atree)
    return 0;

  puts ("amount tree");
  pri_tree(atree, 0);

  puts ("detail tree");
  pri_tree(dtree, 0);

  struct tdata *mxsup = (struct tdata *)atree->data;

  struct tnode *t = atree;
  while (t->right) { // amount tree
    mxsup = (struct tdata *)t->right->data;
    t = t->right;
  }
  printf ("atree: %s supplier is max: %d\n", mxsup->sup_name, mxsup->amount);

  mxsup = (struct tdata *)dtree->data;
  find_max(dtree, &mxsup); 
  printf ("dtree: %s supplier is max: %d\n", mxsup->sup_name, mxsup->amount);

  return puts("") == EOF;
}
```

Очевидно, что `find_max` и `pri_tree` можно тоже реализовать через обобщенную функцию, скажем, `tree_travers` с callback-ами для обработки каждого посещаемого узла.

Аналогично можно делать и функцию удаления дерева и данных его узлов для освобождения памяти (здесь я их не писал).

Сейчас подробнее некогда, появлюсь в воскресенье вечером

**UPDATE**

[[[[@LHh](/users/16664/lhh)](/users/16664/lhh)](/users/16664/lhh)](/users/16664/lhh),

Код для построения дерева суммарных поставок каждым поставщиком
и поиска поставляющего максимальное количество деталей.

```
struct sumsup { // дерево суммарных поставок по поставщикам
  struct sumsup *left, *right;
  char *name; // указатель на имя в узле дерева поставок
  int  sum;
};

// сделаем новый узел дерева суммарных поставок по поставщикам
// скорректируем текущий максимум (если новый поставщик сразу MAX)
struct sumsup *
make_sup (struct tdata *d, char **mxname, int *max)
{
  struct sumsup *r = (struct sumsup *)calloc(1, sizeof(*r));
  r->name = d->sup_name;
  if ((r->sum = d->amount) > *max) {
    *max = r->sum;
    *mxname = r->name;
  }

  return r;
}

// рекурсивный обход дерева поставок
void 
max_sum (struct tnode *t, struct sumsup **ps, char **mxname, int *max) 
{
  if (t) {
    if (!*ps) { // init
      *ps = make_sup((struct tdata *)t->data, mxname, max);
      // это нужно для правильной обработки корня дерева суммарных поставок
      // т.к. он будет найден в начале обработки дерева 
      // и эта поставка не должна удваиваться
      *max = (*ps)->sum = 0;
    }
    int r;
    char *nm = ((struct tdata *)t->data)->sup_name;
    struct sumsup *p = *ps; // дерево суммарных поставок по поставщикам

    // итеративный поиск в дереве суммарных поставок по поставщикам
    while (r = strcmp(nm, p->name)) {
      if (r < 0) {
        if (p->left)
          p = p->left;
        else {
          // и достраивание этого дерева
          p->left = make_sup((struct tdata *)t->data, mxname, max);
          break;
        }
      } else {
        if (p->right)
          p = p->right;
        else {
          // если такого поставщика в нем еще нет
          p->right = make_sup((struct tdata *)t->data, mxname, max);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!r) // или увеличение суммы поставок найденного поставщика
      if ((p->sum += ((struct tdata *)t->data)->amount) > *max) {
        *max = p->sum;
        *mxname = nm;
      }

    max_sum(t->left, ps, mxname, max);
    max_sum(t->right, ps, mxname, max);
  }
}

void 
del_sumtree (struct sumsup *t)
{
  if (t) {
    del_sumtree(t->left);
    del_sumtree(t->right);
    free(t);
  }
}

void 
del_tree (struct tnode *t, int data)
{
  if (t) {
    del_tree(t->left, data);
    del_tree(t->right, data);
    if (data)
      free(t->data);
    free(t);
  }
}
```

А это код в конец main() для вызова построения дерева сумм поставок по
всем поставщикам и поиска максимума

```
  struct sumsup *sumtree = 0;
  char *mxsupname = 0;
  int   maxsum;

  max_sum(atree, &sumtree, &mxsupname, &maxsum);
  printf("greatest: %s (%d)\n", mxsupname, maxsum);

  del_sumtree(sumtree);
  del_tree(atree, 0);
  del_tree(dtree, 1);
```

**UPDATE 2**

[[[[@LHh](/users/16664/lhh)](/users/16664/lhh)](/users/16664/lhh)](/users/16664/lhh), пожалуй, вот такой код построения дерева суммарных поставок выглядит более логичным (и к тому же он короче).

```
// рекурсивный обход дерева поставок
void 
max_sum (struct tnode *t, struct sumsup **ps, char **mxname, int *max) 
{
  if (t) {
    struct sumsup *p;

    if (p = *ps) { // дерево суммарных поставок по поставщикам уже существует
      int r;
      char *nm = ((struct tdata *)t->data)->sup_name;

      // итеративный поиск в дереве суммарных поставок по поставщикам
      while (r = strcmp(nm, p->name)) {
        if (r < 0) {
          if (p->left)
            p = p->left;
          else {
            // и достраивание этого дерева
            p->left = make_sup((struct tdata *)t->data, mxname, max);
            break;
          }
        } else {
          if (p->right)
            p = p->right;
          else {
            // если такого поставщика в нем еще нет
            p->right = make_sup((struct tdata *)t->data, mxname, max);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!r) // или увеличение суммы поставок найденного поставщика
        if ((p->sum += ((struct tdata *)t->data)->amount) > *max) {
          *max = p->sum;
          *mxname = nm;
        }
    } else // создаем корень дерева поставок
      *ps = make_sup((struct tdata *)t->data, mxname, max);

    max_sum(t->left, ps, mxname, max);
    max_sum(t->right, ps, mxname, max);
  }
}
```

Как видите, в нем создание корня дерева поставщиков не рассматривается как особый случай при поиске максимума.

Comment: Подскажите, как использовать f для поиска Name с наибольшим Const(см. выше)


     void show_Name(Ttree *temp, char nm[30], bool &f){  
        if (temp)
  {
            //if (nm == (temp->Name)) 
            if (strcmp(nm, temp->Name) == 0) 
            
   {
                f = 1;
                cout << "Number of parts:" << temp->Const << endl << "Supplier:" << temp->Name << endl << "Name:" << temp->Name << endl;
            }
            show_Detal(temp->right, nm, f); 
            show_Detal(temp->left, nm, f);  
 
        }
    Если по

Comment: @LHh, не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос.

--

Если Вам нужно напечатать **только** максимальный `Const` для заданного `name`, в дереве построенном по возрастанию `Const` (вроде бы Вы строили его так), то надо **идти по правой ветке и заканчивать работу**, как только нашли поставку.

    void show_Name(Ttree *t, char nm[30], bool &f){
      if (t) {
        show_Name(t->right, nm, f); if (f) return;
        if (strcmp(nm, t->Name) == 0) {
          cout << ... // печать
          f = 1; return;
        }
        show_Name(t->left, nm, f);
      }
    }

Или это не то, что Вы имели в виду?

Comment: У меня вызывает сомнение bool &f. Как сделать f счетчиком количества деталей, чтобы использовать для нахождения наибольшего значения и соответственно связать количество деталей с поставщиком, чтобы распечатать имя поставщика

Comment: @LHh, извините, не угадал.

--

Постарайтесь четко и подробно (на русском языке) написать что Вам нужно сделать (можно даже без кусочков программы).

Какие исходные данные и что Вы хотите увидеть в результате.

--

Понятно же, что переменная типа `bool` принимает только 2 значения (true, false (которые можно записать как 0 и 1)). 

Поэтому мысль о том, что Вам в функции `show_Name` понадобилось использовать `f` как *счетчик* (да еще и связанный каким-то мистическим образом с конкретным поставщиком), просто не могла меня посетить.

Я решил, что `f` от `found` -- признак, что искомое имя нашли.

Comment: Нужно сделать функцию, проверяющую всех поставщиков через обход всего дерева с вызовом функции подсчета количества деталей по каждому элементу. В процессе подсчета найти поставщика с наибольшим количеством деталей и в конце вывести его на экран.Это та часть программы с которой я не могу никак справиться. Данные программы: struct Ttree 
{   int Const;      
    char Name[30];      
    char Detal[30];      
    struct Ttree *left;   
    struct Ttree *right;
Спасибо, что так чутко отнеслись к моей проблеме

Comment: @LHh, так Вам нужно найти максимум из суммарной поставки деталей каждого поставщика или одну максимальную поставку?

Если одну (и дерево построено по величинам поставки), то это будет последняя структура, если все время идти по дереву направо (тут все дерево обходить не нужно).

Если искать максимум из суммарных поставок каждого поставщика, то в процессе обхода дерева, стройте новое дерево с узлами:

     struct sumsup {
       struct sumsap *left, *right;
       char *Name;
       int sum;
     };

по имени поставщика. (Если узел уже есть, прибавляйте `Const` к `sum` и запоминайте максимум).

Comment: Из суммарной поставки. В этом то и сложность для меня

Comment: @LHh, положил примерный код в **UPDATE** ответа. Надеюсь разберетесь (например, с помощью дебаггера).

--


Это мой последний комментарий здесь (На ХК лимит 4 комментария к одному ответу/вопросу).

Если будут вопросы, задавайте, постараюсь ответить в комментариях непосредственно под Вашим вопросом или в **updates** в теле своего ответа.